# Get the status of the the node(created,modified or deleted) in the same script

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

I have a script that gets triggered when something is updated or inserted or deleted in alfresco . And only the Node ID of the changed node is passed to my application's backend. Here, since only the Node ID is passed, I am not able to distinguish which action(updated/entered/deleted) has been done. How do I pass something in the script that would tell us what kind of action is performed in alfresco? Hoping a reply soon

Comment: How are you triggering the script? Behaviour? Rule? Other?

Comment: @Gagravarr I am triggering the script via rules

Comment: Why not setup a different rule for each of Added / Updated / Deleted, and have those rules call different scripts?

Comment: @Gagravarr: Actually our constraint is each of these is calling same script. And that script is passing a node ID of the changed node to the REST endpoint(backend). Hence along with the node id I need another parameter in the script to specify what kind of action has been performed